# check if item is on the list discord python

Tags: python, list, discord

I have a problem I can't figure out. I am doing a discord bot in python.
I have a ghost_list.py (separate file) which has usual_suspects =[500 numbers here separated by,]

```py
from ghost_list import usual_suspects

@bot.command()

async def isidonlist(ctx, arg):

    if arg in usual_suspects:
        nameget = opener.open(f"{api_url}{theme}/{arg}?selections=&key= 
        {api_key}").read()
        namegetdata = json.loads(nameget)
        ghost_name = (namegetdata['name'])
        await ctx.send(f"{ghost_name} is on the list of usual suspects.")

    else:
        await ctx.send(f"{arg} is NOT on the list of usual suspects.")
```

Now the problem is I always get the else result. Which makes me wonder what is wrong with this code. I input the numbers that I know are on the list yet it always shows NOT on the list.
When I use this list in other command which uses
for i in range(len(usual_suspects)):
it works fine.

Is there a different way I should be approaching this or is it just some mistake I am unaware of?
Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is difficult to determine based on the information provided, here is a possible case. `arg` may be being passed in as a `string`. Make sure you convert it into an `int` first, if there are ints in your `usual suspects` list as you said. Revise your code like the following: `int(arg)`